# Pandas: Function Test for Variable Sets Regardless of Value

Tags: python, pandas, function

This bit runs but sets both `Date Option` and `Date Auto` no matter what the value of `Date Type` is:

```
OPTION = "O"
AUTO   = "A"

def calc_date(row, date_type):
    DATE_TYPE = date_type
    MY_DATE = pd.to_datetime(row['my date'], errors='coerce')
    DAYS = row['Num Days']

    if pd.isna(MY_DATE) or pd.isna(DAYS):
        return None

    if DATE_TYPE == AUTO and MY_DATE > TODAYS_DATE:
        DATE_AUTO = MY_DATE -  pd.to_timedelta(DAYS, unit='d')
        return DATE_AUTO.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if not pd.isna(DATE_AUTO) else None

    if DATE_TYPE == OPTION and MY_DATE > TODAYS_DATE:
        DATE_OPTION = MY_DATE -  pd.to_timedelta(DAYS, unit='d')
        return DATE_OPTION.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if not pd.isna(DATE_OPTION) else None

    return None   

def set_date(df):

    new_df = df.copy()

    new_df['Date Auto'] = new_df.apply(calc_date, date_type=AUTO, axis=1)
    new_df['Date Option'] = new_df.apply(calc_date, date_type=OPTION, axis=1)
                        
    return new_df


df_new = set_date(df)
```

Why is it ignoring the test for `DATE_TYPE` but honoring the `MY_DATE` test?

Comment: `calc_date` gets applied twice, once each for `AUTO` and `OPTION`. Why wouldn't it set both?

Comment: @chepner how would you rewrite? I understand but am not sure how to fix.

Comment: PS: I have a working version that uses `iterrows()` and I am trying to rewrite without having to check the value in each row for `date_type` using `iterrows()`.

Comment: It's not clear what needs to be fixed. If you don't want `Date Auto` to be defined/updated, for example, don't use `new_df['Date Auto'] = new_df.apply(calc_date, date_type=AUTO, axis=1)` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that more efficiently (without `.apply` of a custom function, only vectorized Pandas-operations):

```py
... # the column casts
df_test['my date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['my date'], errors='coerce')
df_test['days'] = pd.to_numeric(df_test['days'], errors='coerce')
df_test['months'] = pd.to_numeric(df_test['months'], errors='coerce')

mask = df_test["my date"].dt.date > pd.Timestamp.now().date()
days = pd.to_timedelta(df_test.loc[df_test["days"].notna(), "days"], unit="days")
for col in "Auto", "Option":
    df_test[f"Date {col}"] = (
        (df_test.loc[mask & df_test["my type"].eq(col), "my date"] - days)
        .dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    )
```

Result:

```
     my date my type   days  months   Date Auto Date Option
0 2021-12-31    Auto   20.0    12.0         NaN         NaN
1 2025-01-01    Auto   30.0    36.0  12/02/2024         NaN
2        NaT            NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN
3        NaT            NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN
4 2024-01-22  Option  180.0    48.0         NaN  07/26/2023
```

Comment: I'm eventually going to put this is a class/library that will be used by many notebooks so I want to keep most of the logic in functions ...etc. But I'm open to suggestions there. I will use some of your answer to improve mine.

Comment: @KilgoreTrout You can adapt that easily into a function. I didn't because I only wanted to demonstrate the use of native Pandas methods.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for. I will incorporate the vectorized bits into the function.

Comment: This fails with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'str'`

Comment: @KilgoreTrout At the beginning there' s the `... # the column casts`: by that I mean the 3 type conversions in your solution (directly after the `df_test` definition) - now edited in.

Answer (score 0):

A few tweaks and we have a working version:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'my date': ['12/31/2021', '01-01-2025', '','','22 jan 2024'],
                        'my type': ['Auto','Auto','','','Option'],
                        'days': ['20', '30', '','','180'],
                        'months': ['12','36','','','48']})

df_test['my date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['my date'], errors='coerce')
df_test['days'] = pd.to_numeric(df_test['days'], errors='coerce')
df_test['months'] = pd.to_numeric(df_test['months'], errors='coerce')

def calc_date(row):
    DATE_TYPE = row['my type']
    MY_DATE = pd.to_datetime(row['my date'], errors='coerce')
    DAYS = row['days']

    if pd.isna(MY_DATE) or pd.isna(DAYS):
        return row

    if DATE_TYPE == FIXED_AUTO and MY_DATE > TODAYS_DATE:
        DATE_AUTO = MY_DATE -  pd.to_timedelta(DAYS, unit='d')
        row['Date Auto'] = DATE_AUTO.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if not pd.isna(DATE_AUTO) else None

    if DATE_TYPE == FIXED_OPTION and MY_DATE > TODAYS_DATE:
        DATE_OPTION = MY_DATE -  pd.to_timedelta(DAYS, unit='d')
        row['Date Option'] = DATE_OPTION.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if not pd.isna(DATE_OPTION) else None

    return row

def set_date(df):
    new_df = df.apply(calc_date, axis=1)
                        
    return new_df

new_df = set_date(df_test)
```

OUTPUT:

|  | Date Auto | Date Option | days | months | my date | my type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN | 20.0 | 12.0 | 2021-12-31 | Auto |
| 1 | 12/02/2024 | NaN | 30.0 | 36.0 | 2025-01-01 | Auto |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaT |  |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaT |  |
| 4 | NaN | 07/26/2023 | 180.0 | 48.0 | 2024-01-22 | Option |